# Please recommend a tutoring website, for when my questions are too simple

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question, and my question got 2 negative votes. The way I understand is my question was too easy/simple and beginner-like. So, I would like you to recommend me a platform or online tutoring website etc. for my questions.

Comment: If you did your research and put effort in your question you will do just fine on Stack Overflow. Keep in mind to ask specific questions though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20142558/1079354)...

...then I wouldn't argue that it's too simple.  Any question can be extremely straightforward, and there shouldn't be any prejudice to a simple problem.

The main issue that ***I*** see with it is that it demonstrates a lack of effort or attempt to research the problem beforehand.  It's more or less a homework dump - I need to solve X, how do I solve X.

I wouldn't let downvotes get you down too much - if you add more "here's what I tried" to these sorts of questions, people tend to look at them more favorably.